# Fill value backwards from occurence by group with condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**Problem:** I would like to fill a value backwards from occurrence by group with a condition. I am trying to generate column C in the desired output.

Set C equal to B and fill 1 backwards if A is <= 35, stop fill if A > 35.

I am trying to complete this task using *dplyr*.

Building on something similar to my previous question: [Fill value backwards from occurence by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307787/fill-value-backwards-from-occurence-by-group)

**Input:**

```
DAT_in  = data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,
                       2,2,2,
                       3,3,3,
                       4,4,4,4,4), 
                  time=c(1,2,3,4,
                         1,2,3,
                         1,2,3,
                         1,2,3,4,5),
                  A=c(100,35,25,0,
                      100,75,55,
                      100,28,25,
                      100,30,45,25,0),
                  B=c(0,0,0,1,
                      0,0,0,
                      0,0,1,
                      0,0,0,0,1))
```

**Desired output (C):**

```
DAT_out  = data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,
                   2,2,2,
                   3,3,3,
                   4,4,4,4,4), 
              time=c(1,2,3,4,
                     1,2,3,
                     1,2,3,
                     1,2,3,4,5),
              A=c(100,35,25,0,
                  100,75,55,
                  100,28,25,
                  100,30,45,25,0),
              B=c(0,0,0,1,
                  0,0,0,
                  0,0,1,
                  0,0,0,0,1),
              C=c(0,1,1,1,
                  0,0,0,
                  0,1,1,
                  0,0,0,1,1))
```

Comment: Are you fixed on dplyr as the library?

Comment: I think desired output dataframe `DAT_out` is incorrect. For column A, there is a value of 30 where I think a 35 should be.

Comment: You have an error in your desired output: A should have 35 (for ID 4, time 2)

Comment: @be_green  open for other solutions outside of dplyr

Comment: `B` is always `1` on the last row and `0` elsewhere per ID?

Comment: @roarkz  I made the change to the input. thanks

Comment: @Frank yes B last row 1; otherwise 0 per group ID

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DAT_in)

DAT_in[order(ID, -time), C := as.integer(cumsum(A > 35) == 0L), by=ID][]

all.equal(DAT_in$C, DAT_out$C) # TRUE
```

*How it works*

- Sort backwards from the final period.
- Mark as `1` until `A > 35`.

`DT[i, v := ..., by=g]` only orders by `i` during the assignment to column `v`; the initial sort order of `DT` is preserved.

`as.integer` coerces TRUE to 1; FALSE to 0.

Comment: (OP prefers dplyr, but that package doesn't support "order temporarily during column assignment," so I figured this was worth mentioning.)

Comment: Thanks, nice @Frank

Answer (score 2):

Initially this question was aimed at `dplyr` so here's the `dplyr` solution I came up with. It's much less elegant than Frank's solution, but I already did it so why not write it down "for posterity".

```
Dat_out_step1 <- DAT_in %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(B==1) %>%
  select(-A,-B) %>%
  summarize(max.time = min(time)) %>%
  full_join(DAT_in, by = "ID")


Dat_out_step2 <- Dat_out_step1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(A>35 & time < max.time) %>%
  select(-A, -B, -max.time) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(min.time = max(time))

DAT_out_step3 <- Dat_out_step1 %>%
  left_join(Dat_out_step2) %>%
  mutate(C = ifelse(is.na(max.time), 0,
                    (time > min.time & time <= max.time)*1)) %>%
  select(-max.time, -min.time)
```

**EDIT:**
To Frank's suggestion, instead of using `ifelse()` you can use (in the last block):

```
DAT_out_step3 <- Dat_out_step1 %>%
  left_join(Dat_out_step2) %>%
  mutate(C = replace((time > min.time & time <= max.time)*1 ,is.na(max.time), 0)) %>%
  select(-max.time, -min.time)
```

Old `ifelse()` habits die hard... Thanks Frank for spotting that one out.

Comment: Fyi, `ifelse(x, 0, y)` could be `y*!x`, I think. I mention it because `ifelse` has a reputation for being not-great: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow `replace(y, x, 0)` would be a more readable way to go than my multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for `dplyr` solution, will this work?

```
DAT_in2 <- DAT_in %>%
  mutate(C = ifelse(A <= 35 & lead(A) <= 35, 1, B)) %>%
  mutate(C = ifelse(row_number() == n(), B, C))

# Check if DAT_in2 and DAT_out are the same
identical(DAT_in2, DAT_out)
[1] TRUE
```